# Could not find or load main class while running maven jar file

Tags: java, xml, maven

This is my pom.xml file. i give the class name in pom, while running the jar file in command line i got this error "Could not find or load main class". please help me if any body know the answer.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>inndata</groupId>
  <artifactId>FTP</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>FTP</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.inndata.services.File</mainClass>
            </manifest>
         </archive>
       </configuration>

    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs-nfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: how you are running the jar file? could you share the command?

Answer (score 1):

Your groupId is inndata, your main class is under com.inndata.services.File.

Try to change one of this and check. Hope it will help you.

Check also main method in File.class.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your main class `com.inndata.services.File` can not be loaded. Make sure that it exists and features an adequate main method implementation.

If you think everything is OK, please provide more details like the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps,

1."clean install" to clean the project.

2."package install:single" to build the jar with the needed dependencies

Comment: Tried you 2nd command but I get: [ERROR] Could not find goal 'single' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 among available goals install, install-file, help -> [Help 1]
Does this require some special plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You might be running the jar wrongly. Try this

```
java -jar XXX.jar
```